# Added a celing fan in bedroom, need to wire for switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box, 120-240v

I recently added a box to install a ceiling fan in our bedroom. We want to convert the single switch in the bedroom to a dual switch. The single switch thats currently in, turns on power to the top outlet on an outlet panel of two. Anything plugged into that outlet (we keep a lamp plugged in) will turn on when we turn the switch on. So, we want to convert the single switch into a dual switch so that will turn the outlet (lamp) on and the other the ceiling fan. How should this be wired? Its current set up is a single switch on the wall, we ran an independent/2, black, white, ground, from the ceiling fan junction box to the swingle switch that we want to convert to a double. Thank you in advance to everyone![image][image]

Comment: When you say you added a box, did you already have power to the area the box is in (like a lamp) and swapped to a fan box?Or is this a new run entirely? Do you have access to the ceiling where the box is from above? Do you have access to the ceiling from above the switch?

Comment: Sorry, its a new run entirely. Yes I have access to the crawl space/attic to get to the area from above.

Comment: Yes sir, I added a picture of the junction box where the single switch is and the box we added for the ceiling fan. There was no existing wiring going from ceiling box to switch, we ran ran wires to it. Thank you.

Comment: Why'd you run a /2 to the fan instead of a /3?

Comment: What @ThreePhaseEel is asking is really geared towards your fan. Even if you are not using a ceiling fan with a light AND the fan, you could *(or someone else) could in the future. With a /3 you'd have BLACK/WHITE/RED (and ground) and be able to control the fan and the light on the ceiling. You'll also probably need a double ganged box for the switches. (or a triple) unless you plan to place the switches for the fan separately from the current outlet switch. Please revise your original question with some of these details. Can you add the last picture of the switch?

Comment: I can add more pictures later today. But we used the /2, black, white, ground, because the fan we have is a remote sensored fan where it had a receiver and only connects to a black and white. Where we're having trouble is how to convert the single switch to the double switch, so one switch turns on the outlet and the other power to the fan

Comment: The photo of your switch box leaves some thing to be desired. I can't tell what's connected to what.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a universal ceiling fan remote control that uses a battery for power. It comes with a sender and a controller you connect to the fan. The sender works just like a hand held remote except you mount it in the wall. So all you really have to do is to leave the wiring the way it is, use a cut-in box to mount the sender and connect the receiver to the fan. I don't have a link to a site but they are in all of your big box hardware stores.

Good luck